# md-nav-bar using angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

So I'm trying to figure out the best practice to utilize angular-material with angular 1.5 components and am struggling with setting up the md-nav-bar specifically.

Here is a codepen with my current code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEQwaG?editors=1010

Note how the Home tab is not selected even though I am initializing this.currentNavItem during the $onInit lifecycle hook.

I would expect this to work although there is probably some unfamiliarity with how component scope works which is causing this behavior.

In my actual project (ES6/Babel), I got this working by injecting $scope to the component controller and following similar logic:

```
$onInit() {

    this.$scope.currentNavItem = '/home';

    this.$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', (event, current) => {
        this.$scope.currentNavItem = this.$location.path();
    });
}
```

I feel that this is not the best way to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to use `controllerAs` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/NAyAym?editors=1010)

JS

```
angular
  .module("MyApp", ["ngMaterial"])
  .component('test', {
    template: '<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="vm.currentNavItem"><md-nav-item md-nav-sref="home" name="/home">Home</md-nav-item><md-nav-item md-nav-sref="about" name="/about">About</md-nav-item></md-nav-bar>',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.$onInit = function() {
        vm.currentNavItem = "/home"
      }
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    bindToController: true
  });
```

[John Papa controllerAs reference](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y075)